# How can I check if a variable is empty or not in tcsh Shell?

Tags: csh, tcsh

IF I have to check that if a variable is empty or not for that in bash shell i can check with the following script:

```
if [ -z "$1" ] 
then
    echo "variable is empty"
else 
    echo "variable contains $1"
fi
```

But I need to convert it into tcsh shell.

Comment: [Are you sure you should convert it to `tcsh`?](http://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)

Comment: Tcsh is not suitable for programming, but try this: `if ("x$1" == "x")`.

Comment: That is not an answer to the question asked. The question was TCSH.

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The standard warnings regarding use of `tcsh`/`csh` apply (don't use it for *scripting*, due to its [inherent limitations](https://www.grymoire.com/unix/CshTop10.txt)), but here's the translation:

```
if ( "$1" == "" ) then      # parentheses not strictly needed in this simple case
    echo "variable is empty"
else 
    echo "variable contains $1"
endif
```

Note, though, that if you were to use an arbitrary variable name rather than `$1` in the above, the **statement would break if that variable weren't defined yet** (whereas **`$1` is always defined**, even if unset).

---

To plan for **the case where a variable, say `$var`, may not be defined**, it gets tricky:

```
if (! $?var) then       
  echo "variable is undefined"
else
  if ("$var" == "")  then
      echo "variable is empty"
  else 
      echo "variable contains $var"
  endif
endif
```

The **nested `if`s are required** to avoid breaking the script, as `tcsh` apparently doesn't short-circuit (an `else if` branch's conditional will get evaluated even if the `if` branch is entered; similarly, both sides of `&&` and `||` expressions are seemingly *always* evaluated - this applies at least with respect to use of undefined variables).

Comment: or, perhaps ...
`test $?var -eq 1 && ( echo "defined as ${var}"; echo "nothing to fix"; ) || ( echo "var not defined, using default"; setenv var ${DEFAULT_VAR}; )`

Answer (score 2):

You can try this ([found here](http://www.unix.com/shell-programming-scripting/46228-checking-empty-string-tcsh.html)):

```
set name
if ( ${%name} == 0 ) then
        echo " Variable name has 0 characters as value."
endif
```

Note that the person who posted this has the following signature:

> Standard advice: avoid csh family for scripting.

Note: This will break if name is an environment variable.

```
setenv name foobar ; set name ; echo '+++'$name'+++' ; unset name ; echo '==='$name'==='

++++++
===foobar===
```

Comment: The second part of this answer was an edit suggested by an anonymous user, which seems to be about variables masking environment variables with the same name. I'm not really sure that it is relevant to the question but I'm leaving it here in case it is useful to someone.

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: see comment below.

```
if ( $?1 ) then
    echo "variable is empty"
else 
    echo "variable contains $1"
endif
```

Comment: You have the condition backwards. The behavior of `$?1` seems different from the behavior of `$?foo`; it appears that `$1` is always set, even if no corresponding argument was passed (which is why your solution works if you reverse the condition). `csh`, as opposed to `tcsh`, doesn't permit `$?1`.

Comment: oops, yes, you are right. Although i get the same also for tcsh, $?! always defined.