# CLASSPATH adding in csh even when CLASSPATH is not set

Tags: unix, classpath, tcsh

I would like to have a script to add /path/to/hoge in CLASSPATH by csh.

```
setenv CLASSPATH ${CLASSPATH}:/path/to/hoge
```

However, it returns an error, that says, No match error.

It is beause CLASSPATH was unset.

How can I deal with the possibility where CLASSPATH is not set?

Comment: Related: [How can I check if a variable is empty or not in tcsh Shell](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22640093/how-can-i-check-if-a-variable-is-empty-or-not-in-tcsh-shell).

Answer (score 1):

This looks simple, using Mark's ref.:

```
if ( "${CLASSPATH}" == "" ) then
    setenv CLASSPATH /path/to/hoge
else 
    setenv CLASSPATH ${CLASSPATH}:/path/to/hoge
endif
```