# How to check if environment variable is set in CSH?

Tags: linux, csh

I am writing a CSH script where I need to check if environment variables XYZ or ABC are set or not set in terminal.

If these variables are set then I need to check  if any of them is set to FALSE". 
I'm trying it as below :

```
if ( !($?ABC) ) then

   echo "variable is not set"

else if ( $ABC == "FALSE") then

   echo "variable set to false"                

endif
```

But CSH is first replacing the variables. so I'm getting below error :

ABC : undefined variable

Could you please help me solving this ?

Comment: if you define variable inside the script there should be no problem.

also if you define a variable outside the script using setenv, it will work with your script

Answer (score 0):

`$?ABC` evaluates to 0 when unset or 1 when set

```bash
#!/bin/csh

if ($?ABC) then
  echo "ABC is set"
else
  echo "ABC is not set"
endif
```

Answer (score 0):

This answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/22640299/7332147

says that "The nested ifs are required to avoid breaking the script, as tcsh apparently doesn't short-circuit".

Its example (supposed to work) is:

```
if (! $?var) then       
  echo "variable is undefined"
else
  if ("$var" == "")  then
      echo "variable is empty"
  else 
      echo "variable contains $var"
  endif
endif
```

which is slightly different from yours.

Probably, the simple way to solve the issue is to use a single IF to test ABC and, if not set, set it to some invalid value:

```
if (! $?ABC) then
  echo "variable is undefined"
  setenv ABC "-"
endif
```

(just my two cents, I am not a guru in csh).

Answer (score -1):

if you define variable inside the script there should be no problem.

```
set ABC = FALSE
if ( ! $?ABC  ) then

   echo "variable is not set"

else if ( $ABC == "FALSE") then

   echo "variable set to false"

endif

echo "ABC is still: $ABC"
```

output:

```
variable set to false
ABC is still: FALSE
```

also if you define a variable outside the script using setenv, it will work with your script

```
setenv ABC FALSE
./your_script.sh
```

output:

```
variable set to false
ABC is still: FALSE
```

the better way will be using command line arguments. passing variables to your script is a way better solution than setenv.

Comment: Hi Amir , Its an environment variable set from outside the script. and my script fails if the variable is not set.

Comment: @XYZ_Linux , well in shell, variable are bound to the current process. so if you run a new shell, it wont inherit your variables. as I said one solution is using export in bash or setenv in c shell(csh).